# About two relative primes $a$ and $b$ whose sum is constant.

Tags: number-theory

$\forall (a, b) \in \mathbb{N}$ who are also relatively prime, whose sum is always $c$ (therefore $a + b = c$ for a given number $c$), and the number of divisors for a natural number $n$ is written as $A(n)$,

> How can I get:
>    $$\sum A(a)\times A(b) : a + b = c?$$

Answer (score 1):

As i remember, the number of natural divisors $\sigma_0(n)$ (You've denoted it by $A$) is [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function). It means, that
$$\sigma_0(mn)=\sigma_0(m)\sigma_0(n)$$
Thus for the given $c$ we have
$$S(c)=\sum_{a+b=c\\ (a,b)=1} \sigma_0(a)\sigma_0(b) = \sum_{a=1\\ (a,c-a)=1}^{c-1} \sigma_0(a\cdot(c-a))$$

Comment: Note that OP is looking for the number of divisors, not the sum. This is still a multiplicative function, but it is not written as $\sigma$ but rather as $\sigma_0$ or $d$.

Comment: But then How is "ab" obtained?